Tery Pratchett and Alzheimer's
Sir Terry Pratchet, the author of books including the Discword series, suffered from mental illnesses in later life leading tragically to his early demise.
I wish to ask a question relating to his alzhimers, and I am not sure if this is the correct part of the SE network to do so, or if I can adequately articulate or research the question, the requirements for this SE site being partically high.
Terry Pratchet's works are unlike many other authors, strongly coming across as if he visited the places he described, seeing and recording the events of his stories, as if for him, they were not fiction, were not made up.
I wonder if this was due to what later became his alzhimers, a real disconnection from reality, that in earlier life he benefited from so tremendously in forging his works.

So it seems like you are interested in studies potentially showing a correlation between Alzheimer and creativity?

Thanks for the comment. Could be, more that Alzheimers causes hallucinations and a partial disconnect from reality, like dreaming when awake. Talking to a characters or seeing, interacting with, learning about a place, created at least partially subconsciously, could be a powerful tool. So I guess yes, Alzheimers and creativity, but creativity caused by artefacts of the Alzheimers, not just a general increase in creativity.
